# Vue 3 : issue in getting onchange event from child component

Tags: vue.js

I made a component to provide a select including a button that reset the select to the initial state (no option selected).
I get well the onchange event in parent when an option is selected but nothing when the reset button is clicked, although the select is reset. In my use case the list is still filtered even when nothing is selected

Here is the parent file :

```js
<template>
  <liste-filter
            :nom="'marque'"
            :label="'Choose a make'"
            :liste="marques"
            v-model="selMarque"
            @change="changefilter"></liste-filter>
  <h1/>  
  <div v-for="vh in vehicules" :key="vh.lib" class="w-full">
    {{ vh.lib }}
  </div>

  <div v-if="vehicules.length === 0">The list is empty</div>

</template>

<script>
import ListeFilter from "./ListeFilter.vue"
  
export default {
  components: {
    ListeFilter
  },
  data() {
    return {
      marques:[{id:"Renault",libelle:"Renault"},{id:"Peugeot",libelle:"Peugeot"}],
      selMarque: "",
      vehicules: [],
      tabData:[{"lib":"Renault","modeles":[{"lib":"Clio"},{"lib":"Captur"}]},{"lib":"Peugeot","modeles":[{"lib":"208"},{"lib":"308"},{"lib":"3008"}]}]
    };
  },
  methods: {
    changefilter() {
      this.vehicules = [];
      for (var i = 0; i < this.tabData.length; i++) {
        if(this.selMarque != "" && this.tabData[i].lib == this.selMarque) {
          this.vehicules = this.tabData[i].modeles;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

And here is the component file ListeFilter.vue :

```js
<template>
  <span class="relative">
    <select
      :name="nom"
      :id="nom"
      :label="label"
      v-model="sel"
      class="w-64 text-sm"
    >
      <option disabled value="">{{ label }}</option>
      <option v-for="elem in liste" :value="elem.id" :key="elem.id">
        {{ elem.libelle }}
      </option>
    </select>
    <button
      v-show="sel"
      @click="reset"
    >X</button>
  </span>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: ["nom", "label", "liste", "modelValue"],
  emits: ["update:modelValue"],
  computed: {
    sel: {
      get() {
        return this.modelValue;
      },
      set(value) {
        this.$emit("update:modelValue", value);
      },
    },
  },
  methods: {
    reset() {
      this.sel = ""
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

I also made a Vue SFC Playground to test [HERE](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#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)

Thanks in advance for your help.

PS : if you know a component that does the same I take it ! (vue-select does not seem Vue 3 compliant)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should be listening for the `@update:modelValue="changefilter"` event instead of the change event `@change="changefilter"`.
It's documented here. https://v3-migration.vuejs.org/breaking-changes/v-model.html#overview

Try changing your App.vue to this.

Here is a [Playground](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#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)

```
<template>
  <liste-filter
                :nom="'marque'"
                :label="'Choose a mark'"
                :liste="marques"
                v-model="selMarque"                
                @update:modelValue="changefilter"
                >
  </liste-filter>
  <h1/>  
  <div v-for="vh in vehicules" :key="vh.lib" class="w-full">
    {{ vh.lib }}
  </div>

  <div v-if="vehicules.length === 0">The list is empty</div>

</template>

<script>
import ListeFilter from "./ListeFilter.vue"
  
export default {
  components: {
    ListeFilter
  },
  data() {
    return {
      marques:[{id:"Renault",libelle:"Renault"},{id:"Peugeot",libelle:"Peugeot"}],
      selMarque: "",
      vehicules: [],
      tabData:[{"lib":"Renault","modeles":[{"lib":"Clio"},{"lib":"Captur"}]},{"lib":"Peugeot","modeles":[{"lib":"208"},{"lib":"308"},{"lib":"3008"}]}]
    };
  },
  methods: {
    changefilter() {
      console.log('change happened');
      this.vehicules = [];
      for (var i = 0; i < this.tabData.length; i++) {
        if(this.selMarque != "" && this.tabData[i].lib == this.selMarque) {
          this.vehicules = this.tabData[i].modeles;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: That works perfectly ! As the select was changing after a reset I thought the event would have fired too, but not here. Thx a lot @bassxzero 